# How can create a require() source with custom path and the output of an arraw prop?

Tags: react-native

I have this array of data in a .js file:

```
export const EXPLORE_CATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'E-Scooters',
    groups: 520,
    iconName: 'Photo.png',
    description: 'Small and big e-scooters',
  },
…
]
```

And in my view, I render a FlatList with a component. This component loads an image as an icon.

```
return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.screen }}>
      <BodyOne style={styles.text}>This is the explore view.</BodyOne>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        data={EXPLORE_CATEGORIES}
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <TwoLineWithIcon
            icon={require('../../assets/images/icons/' + itemData.item.iconName)}
            title={itemData.item.name}
            subtitle={itemData.item.description}
            caption={itemData.item.groups + ' groups'}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

The component has `source={props.icon}` so, in my FlatList's renderItem `icon={...}` prop I would like to chain both path and iconName but failed miserably.

this works:

```
icon={require('../../assets/images/icons/Photo.png'}
```

But I would like to do this:

```
icon={require('../../assets/images/icons/' + itemData.item.iconName)}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic require/imports are not supported in react-native. You might want to modify your code as below

```
export const EXPLORE_CATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'E-Scooters',
    groups: 520,
    iconName: require('../../assets/images/icons/Photo.png'),
    description: 'Small and big e-scooters',
  },
…
]
```

```
return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.screen }}>
      <BodyOne style={styles.text}>This is the explore view.</BodyOne>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        data={EXPLORE_CATEGORIES}
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <TwoLineWithIcon
            icon={itemData.item.iconName}
            title={itemData.item.name}
            subtitle={itemData.item.description}
            caption={itemData.item.groups + ' groups'}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
```